# non-static method cannot be referenced in static context

Tags: java

I researched this around and still can't seem to solve this problem.  I have the following in my program:

```
   public void InsertDB(double price, double shares, String ticker, int id)throws Exception {
   //do some stuff
   }
```

I tried the following within my main class(and got the above error non-static method cannot be referenced in static context):

```
InsertDB(constants[i], variables[i], ticker[i], count);
```

Then I read you must create a new instance so I tried(Testingground is the name of my program) and I get an error saying it cannot find the InsertDB symbol:

```
Testingground myObject = new InsertDB();
```

I'm new to java and kind of inherited this program(I haven't had this problem with my programs), can someone tell me what I can do to get this to work and the logic behind it?(my insertdb class gives me errors if I turn it to static so that approach won't work). I also read that it might work if I changed `public` to `protected` but it still didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you post full code here instead of showing us diff parts ?

Comment: the file is fairly large. I just took the parts I thought were relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate the class itself, not the method `InsertDB()`. You instantiate a class by using the key word `new`. You can refer to the official tutorial on the oracle/sun [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Example:

```
Testingground myObject = new Testingground();
myObject.InsertDB(constants[i], variables[i], ticker[i], count);
```

Methods can also be declared as `static`. In that case you can reference them directly ie. `Testingground.InsertDB(constants[i], variables[i], ticker[i], count);` without constructing an object for that class.

Also by convention method names are camel cased. Read more about naming conventions in java [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: This maybe the conflict but when I do that I get an error: constructor Testingground in class testingground.Testingground cannot be applied to given types;
  required: testingground.Testingground.SolverResult
  found: no arguments

I have another class called SolverResult within the application

Comment: should I create a new class, instead of Testingground..something else and put the class to upload to the DB under there?

Comment: @Lostsoul - your `Testingground` class must have a constructor defined that takes `SolverResult` as an argument. Can you add that constructor snippet in your post?

Comment: Is this what your asking for:
public class Testingground {

   private SolverResult delegate;

Comment: @Lostsoul - I am looking for the constructor method. It could be something like this:- `public Testingground(SolverResult delegate){this.delegate=delegate;}`

Comment: opps sorry, here it is:
   public Testingground(SolverResult delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   public SolverResult getDelegate() {
      return delegate;
   }

Comment: then there's this:    static public interface SolverResult {
      public void solution(double[] constants, double[] variables, double total, String[] ticker);
   }

Comment: @Lostsoul - SolverResult is an inteface per your example. Do you know of a class that implements it?

Comment: I think its this:      Testingground solver = new Testingground(new SolverResult() {
         int count = 1;
         @Override
         public void solution(double[] constants, double[] variables, double total, String[] ticker) {
            //blah blah blah
               //try to insert data into database
               
               InsertDB myObject = new InsertDB();
               myObject.InsertDB(constants[i], variables[i], ticker[i], count);

Comment: I am actually getting a different error now, I tried to take some of the advice below and created a new class file and put it in there(called it InsertDB as above). but now I get exceptions must be caught to be thrown

Comment: if I add throws Exception to the above implemention, I get "solution(double[],double[],double,java.lang.String[]) in <anonymous testingground.Testingground$1> cannot implement solution(double[],double[],double,java.lang.String[]) in testingground.Testingground.SolverResult
  overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception"

Comment: Thanks CoolBeans..it works now. I just added "throws Exception" to everything until I stopped getting errors.  Is there any downside of adding throws Exception to code?

Comment: @Lostsoul - you are actually not on the right track here. You need to first find a class that implements `SolverResult`. You should see a class that looks something like this - `public final class SolverResultImpl implements SolverResult` ...

Comment: I found it and then I added throws Exception. here it is: private void solveImpl(double[] c, double[] v, double t, int n, double r, String[] ticker) throws Exception {

Comment: @Lostsoul - Good deal. You should catch the thrown exception upstream to find out the exact exception.

Comment: Thanks so much. I tested it and it worked perfectly..Thanks a million CoolBeans

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of the class that contains the `InsertDB` method, and then invoke the method on the instance.

Alternatively, you could make the method static, and then you would not need an instance from which you invoke it.

You need to understand that `static` fields/methods are defined on the class itself.  So there is one instance of a static field/method in the entire JVM.  Non-static methods/fields live on the *instances* of the objects -- each object has its own non-static field/method.

Comment: when I make the method static all the commands within it stop working(they are uploading the variables to a database).

Comment: @lostsoul, you didnt show anything that it actually does, so we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate the method name. You have to instantiate the class that the method is in, and then call the method on your object.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare a method as a class.  In java, the methods are supported within their class containers, which can be declared as objects.  If your `InsertDB()` function was in a class (for example, `DataManager.java`, declared as `public class DataManager`), you would do something like this:

```
DataManager dmanager = new DataManager();
dmanager.InsertDB(constants[i], variables[i], ticker[i], count);
```

Comment: Thanks John Right now I'm getting this error now: constructor Testingground in class testingground.Testingground cannot be applied to given types; required: testingground.Testingground.SolverResult found: no arguments I have another class called SolverResult within the application

as mentioned I'm new to java, is it more advisable to create a new file and create a new class for this function?

Comment: You're going to have to post your code, but from what it sounds like, you're trying to declare a Testingground object with a constructor that doesn't exist.  There's so many things that can be wrong though, its impossible to tell you what each compiler error means without looking at the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

A non static method need an object reference (this) to be executed. Static method can be called without an allocated object. So referencing a field type or a class method from inside a static method is impossible, because there isn't an instance of the object on which call the required method.